# Как убрать лишнее пустое пространство между band в JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasperreports

Разрабатываю отчёт в Jasper для заполнения его в Java. Поместил шапку таблицы в `title band`, контент в `details band` и итоговую часть в `summary band` (это всё разные таблицы). Во всех трёх используется одинаковый Dataset.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако при выводе в pdf между таблицами неизбежно влазит этот пробел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, как его убрать?

Comment: Какой layout вы используете? Вообще, посмотрите, может там установлены отступы где-то, вообще такого быть не должно.

Comment: @iksuy В бэндах стоят Free Layout, а также я перебрал все Split type: от Stretch, до Immediate. Пока не помогло.

Comment: Подгоняйте размер бэнда. Ну то есть если шапка высотой 20, то и бэнд высотой 20, тогда всё хорошо должно быть. Если у вас так и есть, то лучше xml приложить. А вообще зачем в разных бэндах делать части одной по сути таблицы? Для этого же специально есть tableHeader, pageHeader, и footerы соответствующие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, долго я пытался утрясти эту проблему, после чего понял, что видимо не до конца разобрался с назначениями бэндов. Почитал ещё. Cместил шапку таблицы в бэнд Details.